# Update datagridview use as database excel file

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, updates, oledbconnection

I have use excel to add data to datagridview. I do not know how to use the update function for all modifications made in datagridview.

The tabel from excel it is simple
ID, Material Description,   Manufacturer,   Manufacturer part number    Supplier,   Supplier part number,   Quantity,   Location

```
        String name = "Sheet1";
        String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                        "test.xlsx" +
                        ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;';";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Update [" + name + "$]", con);
        con.Close();
```

I have tried this, no results:

```
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
            string sql = null;
            MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='test.xlsx';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
            MyConnection.Open();
            myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
            sql = "Update [Sheet1$] set id = '?' where id=?";
            myCommand.CommandText = sql;
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MyConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: What language is this? C#? Please add it to your tags.

Answer (score 0):

> Try something like this:

```
    private void UpadateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  {
        tran = null;
        excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        excelConnection.Open(); // This code will open excel file.
        strSQL = "Update [Sheet1$] set Manufacturer= '" + dgvExcelList["Manufacturer",dgvExcelList.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString() + "' WHERE ID = '" + dgvExcelList["ID",dgvExcelList.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString() + "'";
        try
        {
            tran = excelConnection.BeginTransaction();
            dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, excelConnection);
            dbCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            tran.Commit();
        }
        catch(OleDbException ex)
        {
            tran.Rollback();
            MessageBox.Show("error:transaction rolled back," + ex.Message);
        }
```